# Imagens sumiram em site com CakePhp

Tags: cakephp

Recentemente peguei um site desenvolvido em CakePHP. Fiz a migração dele para 2 diferentes servidores e o site funcionou normalmente. Quando fui fazer a migração para um terceiro servidor, simplesmente ele não gera mais os thumbs como era para gerar.

Nenhum dos thumbnails gerado existe no servidor. Percebi que ele gera os thumbs na hora de exibição, mas alguma coisa faz com que ele gere arquivos inexistentes.

Quem puder ajudar e quiser visualizar o erro basta [acessar o site](http://amaremansa.com.br)

Comment: Talvez haja um cache em disco. Já verificou permissões de diretório?

Comment: verifique permissão de leitura e escrita na pasta /upload/thumb

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema alterando a permissão de leitura e escrita sugerida por @Borachio. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, amigo!